# Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'CourierNew,Italic' warning with fscrawler v2.9

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7, fscrawler

I am running fscrawler on two different CentOS 7.8 machines.  On one machine, I get the following warning when running fscrawler:

```
13:03:28,449 WARN  [o.a.p.p.f.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'CourierNew,Italic'
```

Whereas on the second machine, I don't get this warning.  I tried checking for available fonts on both these machines, but the result is same for both machines.

```
# fc-list | grep "CourierNew"
# fc-list | grep "Courier"
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0611bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0419bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Regular
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0583bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0582bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Italic
```

What am I missing to get rid of this warning? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get rid of this message and I'm not sure it's important.
May be just change the log level for that class?